# CSS - Fix H3 Overlapping At Mobile, Tablet

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, overlapping

I'm developing a site with the Avada WordPress theme. The `<h3>` with the class `title-heading-center` overlaps from mobile to tablet size:

[image]

[image]

I've tried adding multiple styles to this class as you can see from the screenshots:

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
word-break: break-word;
line-height: 33px;
```

The only one that seems to help is `word-break: break-word`, which centers the content at mobile.

What other CSS style(s) can I apply to create spacing between the words in the `<h3>` title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to `line-height: 33px !important` rather than just `line-height: 33px`. While it's not recommended that you **keep** it this way, it's worth trying out to see if this is where the issue is. Notice in your screenshot in the developer tools that this property is currently crossed out and therefore is being ignored.

Alternatively, try changing the height of its container div with class `fusion-title`. There may be a container div somewhere in there that's preventing the words from being the correct `line-height`.

Comment: Thanks, had to add a media query but this at least helped get me on the right track!